# Show text while I Hope in Angular2

Tags: angular

IN my Angular 2 app I would like to disable the button while waiting for the response from the server. Here is my sample code:

```
 this.service.insert(url , this.object).subscribe(

        param => {
             I get answer to server
        },  error => {
            I get message error from server.
        }, () => {
            console.log('All Angular' , this);
        });
```

Comment: Your question and code are both unclear. Do you mind rephrasing it a bit and please explain what do you want to do? Do you want to have a progress bar, that shows 20, 40, 60% progress or just a simple loader until the server returns the response?

Comment: I want disabled a button while my server is thinking, so , I need know the property the angular while I hope answer to server.

Comment: Use a boolean flag that you toggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a property in your Angular component:
`isBtnDisabled: boolean;`
Add it to the top of the class.

Then lets add few edits to your code:

```
insert(){
    this.isBtnDisabled = true; // you just started the request and want to prevent user from clicking the btn again

    this.service.insert(url , this.object)
        .subscribe(
            param => {
                 // success - you get answer from server
                 // make your app respond to it by showing the message, updating the UI, whatever                 
            },  error => {
                // error - you get error message error from server.
            }, () => {
                // final - will always run
                console.log('All Angular' , this);
                this.isBtnDisabled = false; // make the btn clickable again
            });
}
```

Now you need to hook up `isBtnDisabled` property to the actual button DOM element in your template

```
<button (click)="insert()" [disabled]="isBtnDisabled">Insert</button>
```

So if `isBtnDisabled` is true it will set `disabled` attribute on the button. Pretty self-explanatory.

Here's just a cherry on the top. Style your disabled button using CSS 'attribute' selectors.

```
button[disabled]{
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```